# How does the browser respond if the Content Security Policy is different across multiple HTTP responses from the same Origin

Tags: security, web, browser, cross-domain, content-security-policy

If a browser requests a resource from a URI, and the CSP header from the first response indicates only to load resources from 'self', ie:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

But subsequent requests for resources to the same origin return a more lenient CSP in their header, ie:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' *.trusted.com
```

Does the browser apply the most permissive policy indicated?

Comment: The browser does not persist CSP policies across responses, and doesn’t between responses maintain any state information about policies from previous responses. Instead the browser enforces CSP policies per-request, per-document. So the browser just uses whatever CSP policy is delivered with each request. The browser doesn’t remember what policies might have been delivered in previous responses. So the browser never makes any evaluation of whether a policy delivered in one response is more permissive or less permissive than a policy delivered in some previous response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The browser does not persist CSP policies across responses, and doesn’t between responses maintain any state information about policies from previous responses." - as above